# Как правильно в Main прописать путь к test.fxml и к test.db? Java

Tags: java, maven

Как правильно прописывать пути к ресурсам в Java?
Доброго всем дня. В данный момент изучаю java. Разработку веду в intellij idea. 
Взялся реализовать простой справочник используя javafx. БД sqlite, для подключения maven подтягивает необходимые библиотеки. Все работает пока запускаешь из idea и перестает работать после сборки в jar. В процессе изучения понял что не тем собирал и с путями у меня полная неразбериха. 
Потому вопрос - как правильно прописать пути к папке resources?
В idea когда создаешь maven project имеем следующую структуру

```
src
--main
----java
------Main
----resources
------db
--------test.db
------test.fxml
--test
pom.xml
```

Как правильно в Main прописать путь к test.fxml и к test.db?
На данный момент fxml (перенес его в корень к Main) получаю через

```
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("main.fxml"));
```

Но по мне так не верно.
Почему при вызове

```
System.out.println(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("test.db"));
```

из Main
В терминале выдает

```
file:/E:/JavaProjects/test/target/classes/test.db

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    
        UTF-8
    
    maven
    maven
    1.0

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifestFile>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java/ru/varizo/maventest/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.txt</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Comment: у вас файл находится в db папке. поэтому нужно писать `getResource("db\test.dbl")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у вас файл находится в db папке. поэтому нужно указывать расположение файла внутри ресурса

```
URL resource = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("db/file.db");

File f = new File(resource.toURI());
System.out.println(f.exists());
```

результат `true`

Comment: Проверил. Работает. Но возник вопрос - если я правильно понял после упаковки всего моего добра в jar я не смогу открыть файл db. Да и не нужен он там. Его можно положить рядом. В таком случае как  к нему обращаться?

Comment: 1) ты можешь добавить в jar. 2) добавить в classPath и сможешь получить доступ

Comment: Простой пример. Есть Main рядом лежит txt/info.txt.FileReader file = new FileReader(new File(Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("txt/info.txt").getPath()));
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(file); отрабатывает. Но стоит собрать все это в jar то выдает такую ошибку  Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\E:\***\***\target\maven-1.0.jar!\txt\info.txt (Синтаксическая ошибка в имени файла, имени папки или метке тома)

Comment: покажите ваш Pom

Comment: Написал в начале

Comment: странно. предлагаю задать новый вопрос